# How to use sqlite3 to clean data

Tags: database, sqlite, data-cleaning

I have constructed a database using DB Browser by simply inserting all csv files which contains several tables, and the table looks like this:

sqlite> .schema P2012_EBITDA
CREATE TABLE `P2012_EBITDA` (
        `Mark`  ,
        `Companyname`   ,
        `BvDIDnumber`   ,
        `CountryISOCode`        ,
        `Dateofincorporation`   ,
        `Cons.code`     ,
        `Lastavail.year`        ,
        `ClosingdateLastavail.yr`       ,
        `Numberofavailableyears`        ,
        `NACERev.2Corecode(4digits)`    ,
        `BVDindependenceindicator`      ,
        `Type(s)ofaccountsavailable`    ,
        `Typeofentity`  ,
        `EBITDAthUSDLastavail.yr`       ,
        `EBITDAthUSDYear-1`     ,
        `EBITDAthUSDYear-2`     ,
        `EBITDAthUSDYear-3`     ,
        `EBITDAthUSDYear-4`     ,
        `EBITDAthUSDYear-5`     ,
        `EBITDAthUSDYear-6`     ,
        `EBITDAthUSDYear-7`     ,
        `EBITDAthUSDYear-8`     ,
        `EBITDAthUSDYear-9`
);

sqlite> SELECT * FROM P2012_EBITDA LIMIT 1;
1|ROYAL DUTCH SHELL PLC|GB04366849|GB|05/02/2002|C2|2010|31/12/2010|6|0610|A+|Cons. & Uncons.|Industrial company|51,927,636|36,122,919|65,082,035|62,494,114|57,180,747|56,649,160||||

Now I need to transform the data such that a BvD ID and the accounting year uniquely identify a record. First, decide which year is the “last available accounting year”(0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9). Suppose the account closing date for a record is 2012/7/1 or after, then define the last available accounting year as 2012. If the closing date is 2012/6/30 or before, define the last available accounting year as 2011. Second, transform all the relative years ( to absolute accounting years (e.g., if the last available accounting year is 2011, then the absolute years are 2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2003, 2002). Finally, reshape the data from the “wide form” to “long form”. Since now a BvD ID + accounting year uniquely identifies a record, you can set the primary key to BvD ID and accounting year.

Much appreciated!

Comment: The process of massaging data into the form you actually need for your database is known as [ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load), and much of it is probably best done outside of SQL in other languages. I like perl, others will argue for python or something else...

Comment: Thanks so much! As I only know python, I'm trying to use python to solve this problem.